# Problems wit redirect URI Flutter

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, oauth, spotify

I tried, to authenticate my App at Spotify, via FlutterWebAuth2, but I always, get a "Illegal redirect Uri" Error.

My authentication function

```
    try {
      var redirectURI = 'beatrunner:/';
      final result = await FlutterWebAuth2.authenticate(
        url:
            "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri= $redirectURI&scope=user-read-currently-playing&response_type=token&state=123",
        callbackUrlScheme: "beatrunner",
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
}
```

My Android Manifest file

```
<activity android:name="com.linusu.flutter_web_auth2.CallbackActivity" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth2">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="beatrunner" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I tried to solve my Problem using this articlehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/58244209/flutter-oauth2-problems-with-redirect-uri, but I still get a error message.

Comment: Missing second slash beatrunner://?

Comment: I tried, but it neither helped

Comment: Take a look at the rules here: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/app-settings/.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot. Sorry for my stupid questions. I forgot,  to add my redirect Uri to the console.